# Passing a node refernce id to a form via hook_form_alter()

Tags: 7, forms, hooks, nodes

using Drupal 7

I'm trying to write a module that alters the node add form of a certain content type. This content type has a node reference field that normally displays as a drop-down. I'm also attaching this node add form to the bottom of the content it references, what I'm trying to do is populate the node reference field by using `hook_form_alter()` and passing in `arg(1)` of the page (passing it the nid of node I want it to reference).

I'm trying to figure out exactly how to do this. I've tried to do a `drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($form, TRUE) .'</pre>');` on the form to see how exactly to pass in the node reference, but it just prints out a huge nested array, and I'm unable to really figure out how I would format that as input I know it's going to look something like this;

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == "my_node_form")
    {
        $form['title']['required'] = FALSE;
        $form['node_reference_field_name']['nid'] = arg(1);    
    }

}
```

but I'm still really confused on the actual syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, figured this out incase anyone is interested, may only work for my use case but perhaps it will help someone else.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == "rating_node_form")
    {
        // dont require title
        $form['title']['required'] = FALSE;
        // validate
        $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validate';
        // call after form is built
        $form['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_after_build';
    }
}

function mymodule_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
       //set the nid to the argument of the nide you are viewing
       $form['field_bar_name']['und']['nid']['#value'][0] = arg(1);
       //set the default value
       $form['field_bar_name']['und'][0]['nid']['#default_value'] = arg(1);
       //set form value
       $form['field_bar_name']['und'][0]['nid']['#value'] = arg(1);
       return $form;
}
```

Comment: also, for some reason you need to have the node reference url widget enabled, I suppose this has something to do with arg(1) being available.